# Botium- Scripting Memory

Tags: robotium

Parameters define by `SCRIPTING_MEMORY` were not recognize during test execution

I have set the "Hide advanced Scripting setting" :

```
text matching mode :none
normalize texte:disable
expend conversation : enable
convo Expansion mode : use all utterances
Expand Utterances to Conversations:disable
Enable Scripting Memory : enable
Scripting Memory mode : Capture word characters only
Expand Scripting Memory : enable
```

code:

```
"#begin
SET_SCRIPTING_MEMORY name|Test1

"#me
$name
```

screenshot :

`$name` Variable is not replace by its value.

Parameters `$name` is recognize as text instead of recognize as variable.

Which parameters I have to change so that botium recognize its?

Comment: It looks good. Could you send logs? (you can turn them on with setting DEBUG env variable to __botium*__. For example so: __export DEBUG=botium*__)

Maybe you use old version? Which version are you using? (how you get it depends on the tool you use)

Comment: I had install botium with docker command : npm install -g botium-cli

and now i lunch application by using file : docker-compose-all.yml

Comment: In the file package.json my version is 1.5.1

Comment: could you send logs please?